# how to load different version of Cuda in ubuntu?

Tags: tensorflow, cuda

I am trying to use cuda 9.0 on a company's computing facilities. After I log in, I use the command `nvcc --version` to identify what the current version of cuda is being loaded. The command returns

> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
>
> Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
>
> Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
>
> Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61

I then use the command `module av cuda` to indentify what versions of cuda is avalilabel. The command returns

> ----------------------------- /alt/applic/spack/modules/linux->ubuntu16.04-x86_64 -----------------------------
>
> cuda/6.5.14/gcc-7.2.0-ijjnj2a
>
> cuda/9.0.176/gcc-7.2.0-lxmyjxx
>
> cuda/7.5.18/gcc-7.2.0-abx65q6
>
> cuda/9.2.88/gcc-7.2.0-cqfnheu
>
> utility.c(2245):ERROR:50: Cannot open file >'/alt/applic/spack/modules/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/cuda/8.0.61' for >'reading'
>
> -------------------------------------- /alt/applic/modules/modulefiles >---------------------------------------
>   cuda/4.0

SO it shows that cuda/9.0 is available (it is wired that it has an error regarding to cuda/8.0...). Then I try to load this cuda/9.0 with command

```
module load modules.new

module load cuda/9.0.176/gcc-7.2.0-lxmyjxx
```

Then I enter again the command `nvcc --version` but it still returns `cuda/8.0` but not `cuda/9.0`...

What should I do to load cuda/9.0? Also, how can I find the path to this cuda/9.0? I tried to use `locate cuda` but it only returns the information of cuda/8.0, nothing else.

Thank you!

---

update:

I found the dir of cuda/9.0 file, which is under a bit wired location 
`/alt/applic/spack/modules/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/cuda/9.0.176`

So I removed the old dir for cuda/8.0, which is `/usr/local/cuda-8.0`, from `$PATH` and add the new dir as above into `$PATH`. Now, I again type in `nvcc --version`, I got the error msg says 
`-bash: nvcc: command not found`

any ideas?

Comment: `module unload cuda` first. If that fails because the module file is unavailable, you'll have to manually remove cuda 8.0 from $PATH.

Comment: @tera I tried your suggestion. but I still get cuda8.0 after I type in `nvcc --version`. How do I remove cuda 8.0 from $PATH?

Comment: In ubuntu, I open `./~bashrc` and add the desired path to cuda there. This has the advantage that is also user specific and that will last between sessions

Comment: @AnderBiguri please see my updated question. Thx!

Comment: @Covepe are you sure that the path you say contains the full cuda library? can you confirm nvcc is in fact there? That looks like a specific tools (spack in this case) cuda libs location, possibly not containing the compiler (nvcc)

Comment: @AnderBiguri hmm, I think you are right. There is no nvcc under those files. So, what could I do in this case?

Comment: @Covepe so you assumption that you have cuda 9.0 is false, therefore, install it. The common place is `/usr/local/cuda-9.0`

Comment: @AnderBiguri you are right. The issue is not at my end, it's IT's problem. They did not give me enough permission to access CUDA resources. Now the issue is fixed. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, two options:

### 1. Use a PPA (a package repository)

You can add a PPA with a different version of CUDA than your distribution's default, like [this one](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-cuda-toolkit) for example.

### 2. Manually

nVIDIA maintains [download files](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive) for the last revision of all CUDA versions. You can choose your version and download an archive for the Ubuntu version closest (but not newer) than the one you have. What you'll get is an *executable* file which is both an installer and a self-extracting archive.

Installing just CUDA itself manually interferes with nothing - it just gets installed under `/usr/local/cuda-X.Y`. At most the symlink `/usr/local/cuda` gets diverted and you have to change it back. Same goes for the CUDA samples.  Installing the nVIDIA kernel drivers, however, is a different business since that messes with your kernel. It's usually pretty safe, but do be careful and also try to have a backup (perhaps older) kernel available as a boot loader option - just in case.